# The LedgerID Error when adding new peers to a Hyperledger network

Tags: blockchain, hyperledger-fabric, hyperledger

I'm very new to Hyperledger Fabric. I'd like to ask you how to resolve the error I've struggled with.

I've tried to add new peers to my hyperledger fabric network that I downloaded from the hyperledger documentation(https://hyperledger-fabric.readthedocs.io/en/release-1.0/samples.html) after executing the sample network(Build Your First Network sample).

I had modified some certain files so that each organization has 3 peers, and executed the byfn.sh file to check out whether or not it works well with the new peers.

The problem is that when the new peers join the channel, this error message is shown.

> Error: proposal failed (err: rpc error: code = Unknown desc = chaincode error (status: 500, message: Cannot create ledger from genesis block, due to LedgerID already exists))
>
> Peer4 failed to join the channel, Retry after 2 seconds

This seems to want me to modify peer4's LedgerID, but have no idea what LedgerID is and which file contains the LedgerID variable.

Could you please how to modify LedgerID or how to resolve this error so that I can run my network without this error with the new peers?

I would really appreciate if you help me out.

I'm looking forward your comments! Thank you in advance.

Comment: it seems that you adding peer twice to the channel

Comment: Thank you for your comment. Is that because I modified and added the configuration files based on the given peers? But it seems like I modified all things correctly..